# Generate enums of base int

Tags: xsd, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm trying to generate enums from a simple-type of base `int` using the Maven `maven-jaxb2-plugin`. But no enum is being generated.

I can see that the generator is using the bindings-file, since it throws errors if it couldn't find a mapping.

When I change the base to `string` the enum gets generated (but I'm not allowed to change the base).

So do I have something configured wrong, or is it simply not possible?

**xsd-excerpt:**

```
<xs:simpleType name="codeType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
    <xs:enumeration value="200"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="400"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

**bindings-file excerpt:**

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="some.xsd">
  <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='codeType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='200']">
    <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="OK" />
  </jaxb:bindings>
  <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='codeType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='400']">
    <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="BAD_REQUEST" />
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed, that the enum is generated.

**bindings-file excerpt:**

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="some.xsd">
  <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='codeType']">
    <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
      <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember value="200" name="OK" />
      <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember value="400" name="BAD_REQUEST" />
    </jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

See [15.4. Customizing Enumeration Mapping - Red Hat JBoss Fuse 6.0 Developing Applications Using JAX-WS](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/it-it/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.0/html/developing_applications_using_jax-ws/jaxwscustomtypemappingenum) for more details.